# Android AlarmManager Start a service with ringtone

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-mediaplayer, android-pendingintent

I am working on Alarm Manager. I used a service to start and will ring a tone. But the service is not starting. Can anyone suggest about service, Pending Intent and identify the error in my code. The code is copied from net.

This is my AndroidScheduledActivity.java

```
public class AndroidScheduledActivity extends Activity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startalarm);

        Button buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidScheduledActivity.this,
                        MyAlarmService.class);

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidScheduledActivity.this,
                        0, myIntent, 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        pendingIntent);

                Toast.makeText(AndroidScheduledActivity.this, "Start Alarm",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Alarm", "Alarm Started");

            }
        });

        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                // Tell the user about what we did.

                Toast.makeText(AndroidScheduledActivity.this, "Cancel!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is my MyAlarmService.java

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("AlarmService", "Alarm Starting to ring");

        Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), alert);
        mp.setVolume(100, 100);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(400);

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

And my menifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarm_basic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.alarm_basic.AndroidScheduledActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyAlarmService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does your application crash, i mean do you get any exception when alarm triggers? If your application does crash please provide the LogCat here so we can get the clear idea why it's happening.

Comment: No, my app was not crashing as far I was testing. 
And I think my problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Try it, and let me know what happen...

In your manifest.xml file

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ServiceClass" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Also need to check wheather Ringtone is null also.

```
 Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
 Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getBaseContext(), alert);

 if(r == null){

     alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getBaseContext(), alert);

     if(r == null){  
         alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
         r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getBaseContext(), alert);               
     }
 }
if(r != null)
    r.play();
```

Or otherway

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), alert);
    if(mp !=null) {    
        mp.setVolume(100, 100);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a permission in your Manifest file

   ```
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   ```
2. Should check vibrator is null or not.

   ```
   Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);            
   if (vibrator != null)
      vibrator.vibrate(400);
   ```

Comment: Thanks solves some problems. 

But my main problem was not. So, I decided to choose Hardik's answer.